# How to define input data in Tensorflow for 1-rank vectors?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

For a project, I want to train a neural network using Tensorflow.

My training data comes from a CSV file (see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53Ryi.png)). The input elements are thus vectors of 5 floats and my label elements are scalars.
I want to train the network over 100 batches of 50 elements.

As my input data are vectors, I do not know how to define the placeholder's shape (`x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,?????])`). With my current code below, I am getting the following error:

> ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 1 for 'MatMul' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [?], [05, 30].

(see [screenshot for full trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZqSk.png))

What am I doing wrong?

---

```
# coding: utf-8

# In[2]:

import tensorflow as tf
import csv

#get data and divide in batch
csvfile=open('data.csv')
reader= csv.reader(csvfile)
train=[]
label=[]
for line in reader:
    train.append(line[0:4])
    label.append(line[5])

#get test data
testcsvfile=open('testdata.csv')
reader1= csv.reader(testcsvfile)
i=0
train_test=[]
label_test=[]
for line in reader1:
    train.append(line[0:4])
    label.append(line[5])



batch = 50
n_batch = 100


#定义两个placeholder
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,5])
keep_prob=tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

lr = tf.Variable(0.001, dtype=tf.float32)

#创建一个简单的神经网络
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([50,30],stddev=0.1))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([30])+0.1)
L1 = tf.nn.tanh(tf.matmul(x,W1)+b1)
L1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(L1,keep_prob) 

W2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([30,10],stddev=0.1))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10])+0.1)
L2 = tf.nn.tanh(tf.matmul(L1_drop,W2)+b2)
L2_drop = tf.nn.dropout(L2,keep_prob) 

W3 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([10,5],stddev=0.1))
b3 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10])+0.1)
prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(L2_drop,W3)+b3)

#交叉熵代价函数
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y,logits=prediction))
#训练
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr).minimize(loss)

#初始化变量
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

#结果存放在一个布尔型列表中
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1),tf.argmax(prediction,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction,tf.float32))
```

Comment: did you read the [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/placeholder)?

Answer (score 0):

'None' is not necessary for the shape of pleaceholder. 'None' means that this dimension is changeable, but you can also use pleaceholder without 'None'.

For example:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [3], 'x')
x2 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None], 'x')
y = 2 * x
y2 = 3 * x2
with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    ys = sess.run(y,feed_dict={x:[1,2,3]})
    print(ys)

#   this code will ruturn error
#    ys = sess.run(y,feed_dict={x:[1]})

    ys2 = sess.run(y2,feed_dict={x2:[1]})
    print(ys2)

    ys2 = sess.run(y2,feed_dict={x2:[1,2]})
    print(ys2)
```

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be several problems with your code.

**1) Input and Label Definitions**

```
for line in reader:
    train.append(line[0:4])
    label.append(line[5])
```

According to these lines, you define `train = [line[0], line[1], line[2], line[3]]` and `label = line[5]`. So your `train` / `x` is of shape `(4)` (are you ignoring the 5th column `line[4]` on purpose?) and your `label` / `y` is of shape `()` (scalar).

So you would have:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None, 4])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None])
```

All the other dimensions (for the weights and bias of your layers) should be adapted accordingly.

**2) Wrong usage of `tf.matmul()`**

> ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 1 for 'MatMul' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [?], [50, 30].

As displayed with this error you are getting, you are defining an improper mathematical operation, trying to compute a matrix multiplication of a scalar (`x` of shape `()` × batch size) and a matrix (`W1` of shape `(30)` × batch size).

For the matrix multiplication `tf.matmul(x, W1)` to work, supposing `x` of shape `(None, 5)` and `30` hidden nodes expected for this hidden layer, `W1` must be of shape `(5, 30)`, c.f. `x(None, 5) x W1(5, 30) = product(None, 30)`.

The shape of `W2` and `W3` (and probably `b3`) must be edited similarly to define valid matrix multiplications (and to end up with the proper prediction/label shape).

Comment: think you for you perfect answer, but I want to know how do I define the value of axes if I use tensordot?

Comment: I actually edited my answer to clarify how matrix multiplication should be defined here. Tutorials such as this [one](http://adventuresinmachinelearning.com/python-tensorflow-tutorial/) could help also.